# npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for lodash@4.17.12-pre

Tags: node.js, npm, lodash

I see `lodash 4.17.12-pre is released. but npm not able to download this package, its giving no matching version error message.

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/releases

How to download this version of package?

```
npm view lodash

{ name: 'lodash',
  description: 'Lodash modular utilities.',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '4.17.11' },
```

Thanks

SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the actual bits have not been published to `npm` yet. As you can see from `npm view lodash`:

```
lodash@4.17.11 | MIT | deps: none | versions: 104
Lodash modular utilities.
https://lodash.com/

keywords: modules, stdlib, util

dist
.tarball: https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.11.tgz
.shasum: b39ea6229ef607ecd89e2c8df12536891cac9b8d
.integrity: sha512-cQKh8igo5QUhZ7lg38DYWAxMvjSAKG0A8wGSVimP07SIUEK2UO+arSRKbRZWtelMtN5V0Hkwh5ryOto/SshYIg==
.unpackedSize: 1.4 MB    

dist-tags:
latest: 4.17.11  // <-- latest in npm
```

It is not an official release yet so using it from `npm` would not be an option until officially released/pushed to npm as `4.17.12`.

Comment: as of Oct 2020, `npm install --save-dev "@types/lodash@~4"` installs me `"@types/lodash": "^4.14.165"` (so 4.14, not even 4.17). So types seem even further behind?